# NameError: name 'store_id' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, backend

I am doing some rework on a script and this was the starting method:

```
def update_charge_attribute_record(self, charge_id, data, use_new_db_connection=True) -> Optional[ChargeAttribute]:
        ca = None
        try:
            if use_new_db_connection:
                ca = context_aware_db_session().query(ChargeAttribute).filter_by(charge_id=charge_id).first()
            else:
                ca = ChargeAttribute.query.filter_by(charge_id=charge_id).first()

            if not ca:
                ca = ChargeAttribute()
                ca.charge_id = charge_id
                ca.store_id = data["store_id"]

                ca.currency_used = data["store_currency"]

                ## end create section

            if "last_error_type" in data:
                ca.last_error_type = data["last_error_type"]

            # Updates rates if possible.
            if "currency_conversion_rate_store_default_to_usd" in data:
                # currency_conversion_rate_to_usd store to usd ratio
                ca.currency_conversion_rate_to_usd = data["currency_conversion_rate_store_default_to_usd"]
            if "currency_conversion_rate_presentment_to_usd" in data:
                # currency_conversion_rate_to_usd presentment to usd ratio

            if "shipping_rate_conversion_rate_presentment_to_store_default" in data:
                ca.set_general_attribute(
                    "shipping_rate_conversion_rate_presentment_to_native",
                    float(data["shipping_rate_conversion_rate_presentment_to_store_default"]),
                )

            if use_new_db_connection:
                context_aware_db_session().add(ca)
                context_aware_db_session().flush()
            else:
                ca.save()

        except Exception as e:
            sentry.captureException(tags={"service": "ChargeHelper"})
            app.logger.error(
                f"update_charge_attribute_record exception: {e}", exc_info=True, extra={"charge_id": charge_id}
            )
        return ca
```

This method worked with no problems. Now, I have a task to create some kind of helper method which will retrieve charge_attribute record and that method will be called in the already mentioned one. Now it looks like this:

```
def update_charge_attribute_record(
        self, charge_id, create_or_get_charge_attribute, use_new_db_connection=True
    ) -> Optional[ChargeAttribute]:
        ca = None
        try:
            ca = create_or_get_charge_attribute(charge_id, store_id, store_currency, use_new_db_connection)
            if not ca:
                return None
            if ca:
                if "last_error_type" in data:
                    ca.last_error_type = data["last_error_type"]

            # Updates rates if possible.
            if "currency_conversion_rate_store_default_to_usd" in data:
                # currency_conversion_rate_to_usd store to usd ratio
                ca.currency_conversion_rate_to_usd = data["currency_conversion_rate_store_default_to_usd"]
            if "currency_conversion_rate_presentment_to_usd" in data:
                # currency_conversion_rate_to_usd presentment to usd ratio

            if "shipping_rate_conversion_rate_presentment_to_store_default" in data:
                ca.set_general_attribute(
                    "shipping_rate_conversion_rate_presentment_to_native",
                    float(data["shipping_rate_conversion_rate_presentment_to_store_default"]),
                )

            if use_new_db_connection:
                context_aware_db_session().add(ca)
                context_aware_db_session().flush()
            else:
                ca.save()

        except Exception as e:
            sentry.captureException(tags={"service": "ChargeHelper"})
            app.logger.error(
                f"update_charge_attribute_record exception: {e}", exc_info=True, extra={"charge_id": charge_id}
            )

        if ca is not None:  # Additional check before we return ca
        return ca
```

With new helper method:

```
def create_or_get_charge_attribute(self, charge_id, store_id, store_currency, use_new_db_connection=True):
        """
        This method should either create or retrieve ChargeAttribute object associated with charge_id,
        store_id, and store_currency.
        If the object already exists, method returns it, if it does not exist, a method creates new object and returns it.
        """
        try:
            if use_new_db_connection:
                ca = context_aware_db_session().query(ChargeAttribute).filter_by(charge_id=charge_id).first()
            else:
                ca = ChargeAttribute.query.filter_by(charge_id=charge_id).first()

            if not ca:
                ca = ChargeAttribute()
                ca.charge_id = charge_id
                ca.store_id = store_id
                ca.currency_used = store_currency

        except Exception as e:
            sentry.captureException(tags={"service": "ChargeService"})
            app.logger.error(
                f"create_or_get_charge_attribute exception: {e}", exc_info=True, extra={"charge_id": charge_id}
            )
        return ca
```

I am basically making new helper method for some other reworks I am going to need to do in the future. What I need is this to work as the method on top of the inquiry. The message I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "services/charge_helpers.py", line 89, in update_charge_attribute_record
    charge_id=charge_id, store_id=store_id, store_currency=store_currency, use_new_db_connection=use_new_db_connection
NameError: name 'store_id' is not defined
```

This data is created in other files and passed as dict to this update_charge_attribute_record method for update of record. The new method just need to retrieve and create one, as I sad, a helper.

I am bit lost, to be honest, something confused me here.

Thank you in advance!